# Tabbar Images Cut

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

I am using tabcontroller. In the first image screenshot got from storyboard, the second one got from the app on the iphone. Once you look closer to the images in the second image, you could see images are cut at the bottom compared to first screenshot tabbar images. I do not have any idea why this happened.

[image: in the storyboard]

[image: in the app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the correct names as of `filename@2X.png` for Retina and `filename.png` for non-Retina images.

Make sure you **always** use `filename.png` name convention and not the @2x in code.

Make sure you use the right dimension. My `UITabBar` images are some 39x48 pixels for Retina on the iPhone.

I would also advise you to convert to `asset catalogs` as they are enormously easy to use.

Comment: Thanks alot SergiusGee, it worked very well. Could you please elaborate what is asset catalogs?

Comment: @user1724168 great to be of help, friend! Asset Catalog is a new feature in Xcode 5 that really helps you a lot with images of different formats. Here's a nice tutorial on the topic - https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-managing-images-xcode-5-asset-catalogs

Comment: Thanks a lot again, SergiusGee. Appreciate.